# Running websharper.ui.next on OSx complains with a mcs error

Tags: xamarin, xsp, websharper, websharper.ui.next

I've got a websharper project that runs flawlessly on windows. However it only compiles flawlessly on mac but can't be run. The webserver complains that it can find a file (doesn't name it) and reading the stacktrace it seems to be the C# compiler complaining. However being an F# project that's somewhat surprising.

```
System.SystemException
Error running mcs: Cannot find the specified file

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.
Exception stack trace:
  at Mono.CSharp.CSharpCodeCompiler.CompileFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00135] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System/Microsoft.CSharp/CSharpCodeCompiler.cs:216 
  at Mono.CSharp.CSharpCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System/Microsoft.CSharp/CSharpCodeCompiler.cs:136 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00014] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System/System.CodeDom.Compiler/CodeDomProvider.cs:111 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x002e8] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs:822 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs:731 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00264] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:826 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x0011c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:451 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00056] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:396 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00040] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:989 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:972 
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x0016b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs:417
```

ANy suggestions to what could be the root of this problem?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @ninjaboy yup. I've included the resolution I used below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to [mono 4.2 alpha](http://www.mono-project.com/download/alpha/) resolves the issue. I do however think it can be solved with 4.0 as well since I have had the same web site running on a different Mac without installing 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a mono installation issue.  A similar exception is happening in this ticket: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50713/error-running-mcs-cannot-find-the-specified-file

Comment: Unfortunately, the link provided doesn't resolve the issue.